# Can we say "He didn't change very many"?

Tags: word-usage, quantifiers, countability

Can we say "He didn't change very **many**" instead of " He didn't change very **much**"?

Comment: There are places you can say it, but never as a substitute.  "Much" refers to non-countable characteristics, "many" refers to countable things.  "He didn't change very many lightbulbs."  "He didn't change very much despite spending years in a combat zone."

Answer (score 1):

No.

"Many" describes a count of things, whereas "much" describes a mass quantity.

The following dialog is correct, but terse:

> Question:  He was supposed to change the lightbulbs.  How many did he change?
>
> Answer:  He didn't change very many.

Whereas, a person's personality is a single thing.  It can change a little, or it can change a lot.  So it is okay to say "He didn't change very much."  But unless the person suffers from "multiple personality disorder", it is not okay to say "He didn't change very many" when talking about a person's personality.